# I am trying to make a simple Discord bot that tells the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am attempting to make a very simple Discord bot with JavaScript on Mac that tells the time in "2:54" format. I programmed it to answer to `time?` but the console logs error messages such as "cannot send empty messages" or simply the bot doesn't answer.

The connection to the discord client works fine, but the messages don't.

Here is the full code:

```js
var discord = require('discord.js')
var client = new discord.Client

client.login("")
var clientlogin = ("Time bot")

client.on("ready", function() {
  console.log("Logged in as 'Time bot'")
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'time?') {


    var date = new Date();

    var Hour = date.getHours();
    var Minute = date.getMinutes();
    var Second = date.getSeconds();

    var Time = (Hour, Minute, Second);

    client.on('message', msg => {
      msg.channel.send(Time);
      console.log(Time);
    });
  }
});
```

The solution to this problem is probably simple, but I cannot get ahold of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that second `client.on('message'...` as you're already listening for the incoming messages.

Time in `var Time = (Hour, Minute, Second);` will only store the seconds, not the formatted time. However, this bot can be easily made using the [`toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) to format the current date.

You can check the incoming message, if it's `time?`, you can create a new date, format it, and send it:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client();

client.login(TOKEN);

client.on("ready", function() {
  console.log("Logged in as 'Time bot'")
});

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  if (msg.content === 'time?') {
    const formattedTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: 'short' });

    msg.channel.send(formattedTime);
  }
});
```

PS: I'm not sure what you mean by that *"2:54" format*.

Answer (score 1):

You're facing this issue because of this part in your code:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'time?') {


    var date = new Date();

    var Hour = date.getHours();
    var Minute = date.getMinutes();
    var Second = date.getSeconds();

    var Time = (Hour, Minute, Second);

    // This is the badly behaving code!
    client.on('message', msg => {
      msg.channel.send(Time);
      console.log(Time);
    });
  }
});
```

The code inside the `client.on('message', msg => ...` will be subscribed to the message received event, so the next time your bot receives a message it will fire. Since this function does not check for the `time?` content, it will actually keep sending the message in an infinite loop and hit Discord's rate limiting.

Another problem is your time formatting. You could replace `var Time = (Hour, Minute, Second);` with `` var Time = `${Hour}:${Minute}`; `` to make the message display in "hh:mm" format. You can append `:${Second}` after the `${Minute}` part to also display seconds in your messages! (hh:mm:ss)

If you want to make your numbers padded with zeros, you could do `` var Time = `${String(Hour).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(Minute).padStart(2, '0')}`; ``

Comment: I do recommend going with the answer given by @Zsolt Meszaros. The code added checks to make sure the but is not the author, which is great; as well as overall being cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second `client.on('message' msg => {`